# scala generic encoder for spark case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-encoders

How can I get this method to compile. Strangely, sparks implicit are already imported.

```
def loadDsFromHive[T <: Product](tableName: String, spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] = {
    import spark.implicits._
    spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $tableName").as[T]
  }
```

This is the error:

```
Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
[error]     spark.sql(s"SELECT * FROM $tableName").as[T]
```

Comment: What are other types used in Product apart from primitives?

Comment: I want to use a case class and only use primitives. But this snippet above literally will not compile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the source code for `org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits`, you need the type class `TypeTag` for your type, in order for the implicit `Encoder` to exist:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag
def loadDsFromHive[T <: Product: TypeTag](tableName: String, spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] = ...
```

Comment: In my case `T` is a class-level type parameter. I've added `: TypeTag` but I'm still getting that message (I am also importing implicits)

Comment: Needed to add `Encoder` as well, i.e. `[T: Encoder : TypeTag]`.

Comment: Adding `Encoder` as @lfk suggested helps, but it will still generate errors like `Unable to find encoder for type ExtendedProduct`.  One workaround is to have the class `T` be an inline class, so that you can use the usual `import spark.implicits._` which requires a reference to `spark` as a spark session.  E.g.,

import spark.implicits._<br/>
new Product() {<br/>
   override def ...<br/>
}<br/>

Comment: def makeDs[T <: Product: ClassTag: Encoder](ds: Dataset[T]):  
        Dataset[(T, String)] = { ds.map { case (t: T) => t -> "hello" } 
    }

still doesn't compile.  I don't understand. :(